# Multi-level recursion in lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I have a problem with multilevel recursion. I have two numbers `n1` and `n2`. When `counter` is between `n1` and `n2` i want thoose numbers to be in the result, keeping the list internal structure.

```lisp
(defun izdvoj (lista n1 n2 counter)
  (cond ((null lista) counter)
        ((and (atom (car lista))
              (< counter n1)
              (izdvoj (cdr lista) n1 n2 (+ counter 1))))
        ((and (atom (car lista))
              (> counter n2)
              (izdvoj (cdr lista) n1 n2 (+ counter 1))))
        ((atom (car lista))
         (cons (car lista) (izdvoj (cdr lista) n1 n2 (+ counter 1))))
        (t
         (cons (izdvoj (car lista) n1 n2 counter) (izdvoj (cdr lista) n1 n2 counter)))))

(izdvoj '(1 2 (3 (4) 5 (6 (7)))(8 (9 (10 ((11))) 12)) (13 ((14) (15)))) 7 13 0)
```

The result should be `((((7))) (8 (9 (10 ((11))) 12)) (13))`

And I get `(((4) ((7))) (((((11))) 12)) (((14) (15))))`

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What would be the result of `(izdvoj '(a b (c d (e (f))) (g h)) 3 5 0)` ? What os `brojac`? Since `counter` is used when the list is empty all lists in the result should be dotted like `(d (e (f . 6) . 5) . 4)`?

Comment: Could you please use English variable and function names? It is not clear what you are doing.

Comment: brojac is the same as counter and the result of (izdvoj '(a b (c d (e (f))) (g h)) 3 5 0), should be ((c d (e ())) ())

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by returning the index so far as well as the result in the helper. That way you know how to continue when you have done `car` and are ready to do the `cdr`:

```
(defun get-range (list from-index to-index)
  (labels ((aux (list cur acc)
             (cond ((null list)
                    (values (nreverse acc) cur))
                   ((not (atom (car list)))
                    (multiple-value-bind (res cur)
                                         (aux (car list) cur '())
                      (aux (cdr list) cur (cons res acc))))
                   ((<= from-index cur to-index)
                    (aux (cdr list) (1+ cur) (cons (car list) acc)))
                   (t (aux (cdr list) (1+ cur) acc)))))
    (nth-value 0 (aux list 1 '()))))

(get-range '(a b (c d (e (f))) (g h)) 3 5)
; ==> ((c d (e ())) ())
```